# Importing a bit-map image into python says image cannot be opened?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is my code:

```
import random, pygame, sys, math
from pygame.locals import *

def main():
    global surface

    pygame.init()

    surface = pygame.display.set_mode((1153, 649))


    pygame.display.set_caption("Dunkin' Density")

    start_background = pygame.image.load('Balance_to_begin.bmp')
    too_much_left = pygame.image.load('Balance_too_much_left.bmp')
    total_balance = pygame.image.load('Total_Balance.bmp')



    while True: 
        surface.blit(start_background, (0,0))
        pygame.display.update()
```

when trying to run it says the image cannot be loaded ...
They are all within the same file, but it isn't working? :(

Comment: Works on my machine.

Comment: "They are all within the same file, ..." Can you clarify that? You have your `.bmp` files somehow included in the Python source code? That would be a bit ... odd. The `.bmp` files will need to exist in the directory from which you invoke the program (unless it does a `chdir()` somewhere), which may not be the same as the location where the actual `.py` files live...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the .bmp files and your python script exists in the same directory.